# Unable to load configuration file in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, configuration, struts2

I am working on a JavaBrains tutorial and after I finished the lesson, Tomcat says :

```
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
```

Also :

```
Caused by: Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/Users/jasonrodriguez/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/wtpwebapps/TutorialFinder/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:8:83

Caused by: Action class [org.koushik.javabrains.action.TutorialAction] not found - action - file:/Users/jasonrodriguez/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/wtpwebapps/TutorialFinder/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:8:83
```

I went back to check and my `web.xml` has the correct filter mapping :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TutorialFinder</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

      <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>

      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My `struts.xml` has a namespace, action name, and class attributes :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

<struts>
    <package name="default" namespace="/tutorials" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="getTutorial" class="org.koushik.javabrains.action.TutorialAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="failure">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

and my library build path is correct but when I run Tomcat it tells me that the resource is not available and since I am a novice I don't know how to troubleshoot it since there are no red x marks anywhere in my project. I thought perhaps there was a file out of place somewhere but it looks straight to me :

[image]

Perhaps a fresh pair of eyes can catch something I missed. I had a similar problem with this tutorial yesterday and the solution was to provide the class reference that exist on the classpath in my action tag. However, that tag is already looking correct as far as I can tell. My goal is to get the business service I created, executed.

Answer (score 2):

You have written a wrong package name: `org.kouhsik.javabrains.action.TutorialAction` should be `org.koushik.javabrains.action.TutorialAction`.  May be it's just a typo or you have used the refactoring tool to change the package name. In either way you should use it back or use the correct reference in the configuration to the action in the class tag. Another approach is to use convention plugin and create configuration via annotations. In this case you are free of writing references to actions or methods because you place an annotation right to the class or method you want to be configured.

Comment: I made the change and there are no visible errors now but when I compile and run the app it says `Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/Users/jasonrodriguez/Java/apache-tomcat-7.0.47/wtpwebapps/TutorialFinder/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.3.15.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162` but my library path is connected to `lib` like it is supposed to and I have the whole library of jars. Am I missing something?

Comment: As I commented in other question - remove it.

Comment: @JasonRodriguez In each struts2 plugin there's a `struts-plugin.xml` and even it's not related to your question I will suggest you as per Lukasz Lenart said to remove it from classpath configuration and deployment artifacts. Because you are probably not use GXPs in your project that plugin is useless and it prevents you from bootstrap because it requires additional references on classpath related to GXP that are absent or you don't use them.

Answer (score 0):

I know its very awkward suggestion/solution but this worked for me i was missing struts-spring-plugin.jar in my shared lib directory. It was there in my classpath but not in shared lib.

Thanks